# Ocultar /Mostrar submenu de sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Necesito mostrar y ocultar el sub-menú al darle click por ejemplo a la palabra `Libros` y que me despliegue los ítems que tiene. Necesito  el codigo a continuación:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidr").style.width = "300px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidr").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidr {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidr a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidr a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidr .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.sidr .sidr-inner {
 padding: 0 0 15px
}
.sidr .sidr-inner>p {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px
}
.sidr.right {
 left: auto;
 right: -260px
}
.sidr.left {
 right: auto
}
.sidr h1, .sidr h2, .sidr h3, .sidr h4, .sidr h5, .sidr h6 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 24px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
.sidr .sidr-widgets{
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:0 15px;
}
.sidr p {
 font-size: 13px;
 margin: 0 0 12px
}
.sidr p a {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9)
}
.sidr>p {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px
}
.sidr ul {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 15px;
 padding: 0;
}
.sidr ul li {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
}
.sidr ul li:hover, .sidr ul li.active, .sidr ul li.sidr-class-active {
}
.sidr ul li:hover>a, .sidr ul li:hover>span, .sidr ul li.active>a, .sidr ul li.active>span, .sidr ul li.sidr-class-active>a, .sidr ul li.sidr-class-active>span {
 color:#fff
}
.sidr ul li a, .sidr ul li span {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ccc;
 font-weight:normal;
 text-transform:capitalize;
 line-height: normal;
}
.sidr ul li ul {
 border-bottom: none;
 margin: 0;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}
.sidr ul li ul li {
 line-height: 40px;
 font-size: 13px
}
```

```html
<div id="sidr" class="sidr left">
   <div class="clearfix clear"></div>
   <div id="mobile-header2">
           <a id="responsive-menu-button2"  onclick="closeNav()">
                 &times;
            </a>
      </div>
   <div class="clearfix clear"></div>

   <div class="kf-sidebar">
    <div class="row">
        <!--DL Menu Start-->
              <div id="kode-responsive-navigation" class="dl-menuwrapper">
                  <ul class="dl-menu">
       <li><a>Libros</a>
        <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                    <li>Item</a></li>
                                <li>Item</a></li>
                                    <li>Item</a></li>
                          </ul>
       </li>
                      <li><a>Niños</a>
                          <ul class="dl-submenu">
                              <li><b>Edades</b></li>
                     <li>Item</a></li>
                                    <li>Item</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                          </ul>  
              </div>
              <!--DL Menu END-->
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="mobile-header" onclick="openNav()">
   <a id="responsive-menu-button">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Si se puede hacer con **Javascript** seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidr").style.width = "300px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidr").style.width = "0";
}
$("li.submenu > ul").hide()
$('li.submenu').click(function() {
   $('ul.submenu').not(this).find('ul').hide();
   $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
        $('li.submenu > ul > li').click(function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();  
    });
```

```css
    .sidr {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

    .sidr a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .sidr a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .sidr .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    .sidr .sidr-inner {
     padding: 0 0 15px
    }
    .sidr .sidr-inner>p {
     margin-left: 15px;
     margin-right: 15px
    }
    .sidr.right {
     left: auto;
     right: -260px
    }
    .sidr.left {
     right: auto
    }
    .sidr h1, .sidr h2, .sidr h3, .sidr h4, .sidr h5, .sidr h6 {
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: normal;
     margin: 0 0 10px;
     color: #fff;
     line-height: 24px;
     text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    .sidr .sidr-widgets{
     float:left;
     width:100%;
     padding:0 15px;
    }
    .sidr p {
     font-size: 13px;
     margin: 0 0 12px
    }
    .sidr p a {
     color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9)
    }
    .sidr>p {
     margin-left: 15px;
     margin-right: 15px
    }
    .sidr ul {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 0 15px;
     padding: 0;
    }
    .sidr ul li {
     display: block;
     margin: 0;
    }
    .sidr ul li:hover, .sidr ul li.active, .sidr ul li.sidr-class-active {
    }
    .sidr ul li:hover>a, .sidr ul li:hover>span, .sidr ul li.active>a, .sidr ul li.active>span, .sidr ul li.sidr-class-active>a, .sidr ul li.sidr-class-active>span {
     color:#fff
    }
    .sidr ul li a, .sidr ul li span {
     display: block;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #ccc;
     font-weight:normal;
     text-transform:capitalize;
     line-height: normal;
    }
    .sidr ul li ul {
     border-bottom: none;
     margin: 0;
     background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
    }
    .sidr ul li ul li {
     line-height: 40px;
     font-size: 13px
    }
.hide-dl-submenu > li {
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidr" class="sidr left">
       <div class="clearfix clear"></div>
       <div id="mobile-header2">
               <a id="responsive-menu-button2"  onclick="closeNav()">
                     &times;
                </a>
          </div>
       <div class="clearfix clear"></div>

       <div class="kf-sidebar">
        <div class="row">
            <!--DL Menu Start-->
                  <div id="kode-responsive-navigation" class="dl-menuwrapper">
                      <ul class="dl-menu hide-dl-submenu">
           <li class="submenu"><a>Libros</a>
            <ul>
                                        <li class="final"><a>Item</a></li>
                                    <li class="final"><a>Item</a></li>
                                        <li class="final"><a>Item</a></li>
                              </ul>
           </li>
   
                              </ul>  
                  </div>
                  <!--DL Menu END-->
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mobile-header" onclick="openNav()">
       <a id="responsive-menu-button">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: le agrege efecto para que se vea mejor

Answer (score 0):

Buenos, solo tendrías que agregar lo siguiente:

Agregar en el CSS:

```
.hide-dl-submenu > ul {
   display:none;
}
```

En cada `li` principal agregale este evento clic:

```
<li onclick="mostrarSubMenus(this)"><a>Libros</a>
   <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                    <li>Item</a></li>
                                               <li>Item</a></li>
                                    <li>Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
```

En el javascript:

```
function mostrarSubMenus(elemento)
{
 if(elemento.className.indexOf('hide-dl-submenu'))
{
  elemento.classList.remove("hide-dl-submenu");
}
else{
elemento.classList.add("hide-dl-submenu")
}
```

}

Comment: Lo intente, pero no funciono

Comment: Te lanza algun error?

Comment: Ninguno, pero no esconde el sub-menu, queda de la misma manera